# Live only circuit with 3 loads

Tags: bridge-rectifier

Please advice how to design one transformer using full-wave bridge rectifier to control separately for 3 loads. This design is Live only circuit,no ground and neutral.
Do i need more of bridge rectifier? how the connection?
Input [image]AC 240V 50Hz

Comment: You need at least 2 conductors to form a circuit.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to explain. (1) Where did you get the schematic? Did you design it? (2) Which direction is power going through T1? (3) Where is the neutral connection? (4) Why is BR1 pin 3 connected to LOAD1? (5) What is BR1 doing?

Comment: Live only circuits are only possible if you have more than one Live : generally 3 of them, in what is called a 3 phase supply. 3 phase rectifiers and control systems are well known. American 220V domestic supplies are another case, where two 110V Live connections have opposite (180 degree) phasing. You really need to say which of these (or what other type) your circuit is.

Answer (score 0):

According to your circuit, it's not T1 feeding BR1 but the other way round.

Here's the equivalent circuit for easy understanding.

[image]

When D1 is 'off', a winding of T1 is in series with load 1. The winding is also energised by 340 V DC (240 V~ rectified by BR1).

When D1 is 'on', BR1 and T1 are bypassed.

T1 is not a transformer since DC is fed to it.

The purpose of BR1 & T1 is not clear.

D6 & D7 switch loads 2 & 3.